# Is there a way to add "next run" column in apache airflow UI

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to add one more column ex: "Next run" in apache airflow UI? At the moment it shows "Last run" only?

[image]

Also is there a way to categorize the DAGs? Ex : Set1 DAGs and Set2 DAGs, At the moment I do not see any categorization.

Answer (score 0):

In the official version of airflow, you cannot add extra columns to the UI nor group the DAGs on the home page.

But you can clone the project, edit the UI code then build it and use it as a custom version. The problem is that you need to rebase the official project after each new version, if you want to stay up-to-date.

Another option is creating an [Airflow plugin](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/plugins.html) using Flask appbuilder, similar to the home page with the features you need, but you cannot make it a home page.

Answer (score 0):

Good question and thank you for attending the webinar ;).

The addition of the 'Next Run' column in the Airflow UI was included in the release of [Airflow Version 2.2.1](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/release_notes.html#airflow-2-2-1-2021-10-29), specifically, in [commit #17732](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17732)

Updating your Airflow version will add the column to your UI :)

Best,
Mark